# Why LINQ can't find the item with property that Contains specific substring?

Tags: c#, string, linq

My application receive Messages list from server. Message object has 'Text' property. From this list I was trying to find first item where 'Text' contains specific substring.
For example response could contains such elements in list(sequence saved):

```
Text = "mye:service?resp=out&text=some_text&id=854217";
Text = "mye:service?resp=inj&text=some_text&id=854219";
Text = "mye:service?resp=corr&text=some_text&id=854220";
Text = "mye:service?resp=out&text=some_text&id=854223";
Text = "mye:service?resp=inj&text=some_text&id=854227";
Text = "mye:service?resp=corr&text=test&id=854230";
```

Here is how I attempting to get the right item:

```
Message suitableMessage = messagesList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Text.Contains("param") || m.Text.Contains("corr"));
```

It always returns first element, this one:

```
Text = "mye:service?resp=out&text=some_text&id=854217";
```

Viewing list items in the debugger, I see that there are suitable elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only showing the `Text` property of one `Message` object here. Can you post the first two or three `Message` objects from the list? Since you're using 'FirstOrDefault()' it seems pretty obvious that only the first (matching) `Message` element will be returned.

Comment: With the _single_ line above, what do you expect to be the output? That line contains the string that you are searching for and obviously the _whole_ line is returned. Are you expecting to get back just a substring of that line?

Comment: @Steve, updated my question, please check it out

Comment: Is some_text a placeholder for some real text? If so, I guess the text of the first Element contains "param" or "corr".

Comment: @ReneNiediek no, some_text actually do not contains "param" or "core", I was testing with this data

Comment: Then this is highy unlikely. You probably need to share more code. I just built a minimal example based on your information and get the expected result.

Comment: @fs_dm place a breakpoint on the line; when the code breaks at the line press QuickWatch `shift+F9` and copy `messagesList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Text.Contains("param") || m.Text.Contains("corr")).Text` in it to see what is in the element, cause I can't see any reason why you would obtain an element that should be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.FirstOrDefault()` (First or `null` if not found in your case), why do you excpeted to get something different than the first match?

If you want to get an array (or more accurately an `IEnumerable`) of all matches, use `.Where()` instead.

Comment: I just need to find first element with specific substring, it returns first element witch is not contains what I am looking for. Not null nether

Comment: @fs_dm, Please show the whole code, because what you showed should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this example you will see that LinQ works as expected:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messagesList = new List<Message>
        {
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=out&text=some_text&id=854217"},
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=inj&text=some_text&id=854219"},
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=corr&text=some_text&id=854220"},
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=out&text=some_text&id=854223"},
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=inj&text=some_text&id=854227"},
            new Message {Text = "mye:service?resp=corr&text=test&id=854230"}
        };

        Message suitableMessage = messagesList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Text.Contains("param") || m.Text.Contains("corr"));
        //result:
        //suitableMessage == "mye:service?resp=corr&text=some_text&id=854220"

        //verification
        if (suitableMessage.Text.Contains("param"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("param");
        }

        if (suitableMessage.Text.Contains("corr"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("corr");
        }

        //verification 2 - you can replace your LinQ with this code and debug
        Message suitableMessage2;
        string reason;
        string text; // just to make sure that value is not changed by some other thread ...
        foreach (var m in messagesList)
        {
            if (m.Text.Contains("param"))
            {
                suitableMessage2 = m;
                text = m.Text;
                reason = "param";
                break;
            }

            if (m.Text.Contains("corr"))
            {
                suitableMessage2 = m;
                text = m.Text;
                reason = "corr";
                break;
            }
        }

        // verification 3 - replace lambda with method if not sure how to add break point, write logs if cant debug runtime
        Message suitableMessage3 = messagesList.FirstOrDefault(DebugLinq);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool DebugLinq(Message m)
    {
        if (m.Text.Contains("param"))
        {
            // log Text, "param"
            return true;
        }

        if (m.Text.Contains("corr"))
        {
            // log Text, "corr"
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all involved. All because of my inattention, and incorrect names of extension methods. In one of the libraries used in the project there is an extension method for the list which is called "FirstOrDefult". This method, apparently, in my case always returns the first element. Including LINQ namespace did the trick, and now all works as expected